# Removing Decimal from number by VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a bit of VBA code in Excel to remove the decimal separator in a textbox that contains a number. The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

TextBox1 = Format(TextBox1, "Standard")

End Sub
```

But it doesn't work properly. The final result has the separator for thousand and also has the decimal place.

This TextBox is not an input data entrance, in fact, it is an output display for a hidden cell. It related to a cell ("B15") that the cell is set on Separator Thousand Group (On) and No Decimal Place (Off). But the TextBox1 shows the Numbers with Separator T.Group (On) with Decimal Place (On). I need a syntax of VB code for keeping Separator T.Group without Decimal Place.
Any idea for removing the decimal separator is welcome!

Comment: `TextBox1 = Format(TextBox1, "0")`

Comment: Thank you Dear @braX ,, but after writing the code the number lost the Separator for Thousand group! I need Separator Group + without Decimal Place together. do you have any idea?

Comment: TextBox1.Text = Format(TextBox1.Text, "#,###,###,##0")

Comment: Well done braX ,, Thank you, it's worked properly ... :)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the user is providing the input, this is an X-Y problem IMO: your goal is to ensure your user can only type digit characters in that textbox, not to *truncate decimals*.

The problem is that a textbox' `Change` event is fired too late to do that. Instead, handle `KeyDown` - I'd do something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If Not KeyCodeValidator.IsValidDigitInput(KeyCode.value) Then KeyCode.value = 0
End Sub
```

Have a `KeyCodeValidator` standard module:

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Public Function IsValidAlphaInput(ByVal keyAscii As Long, Optional ByVal allowDeletion As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal allowNav As Boolean = True) As Boolean
    IsValidAlphaInput = (keyAscii >= vbKeyA And keyAscii <= vbKeyZ) Or (allowDeletion And IsDeletion(keyAscii)) Or (allowNav And IsNavKey(keyAscii))
End Function

Public Function IsValidDigitInput(ByVal keyAscii As Long, Optional ByVal allowDeletion As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal allowNav As Boolean = True) As Boolean
    IsValidDigitInput = (keyAscii >= vbKey0 And keyAscii <= vbKey9) Or (keyAscii >= vbKeyNumpad0 And keyAscii <= vbKeyNumpad9) Or (allowDeletion And IsDeletion(keyAscii)) Or (allowNav And IsNavKey(keyAscii))
End Function

Public Function IsValidAlphanumericInput(ByVal keyAscii As Long, Optional ByVal allowDeletion As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal allowNav As Boolean = True) As Boolean
    IsValidAlphanumericInput = IsValidAlphaInput(keyAscii) Or IsValidDigitInput(keyAscii) Or (allowDeletion And IsDeletion(keyAscii)) Or (allowNav And IsNavKey(keyAscii))
End Function

Public Function IsValidDecimalInput(ByVal keyAscii As Long, ByVal contents As String) As Boolean
    If IsValidDigitInput(keyAscii) Or keyAscii = Asc(".") Then
        IsValidDecimalInput = IsNumeric(contents & Chr$(keyAscii))
    End If
End Function

Private Function IsDeletion(ByVal keyAscii As Long) As Boolean
    IsDeletion = keyAscii = vbKeyDelete Or keyAscii = vbKeyBack
End Function

Private Function IsNavKey(ByVal keyAscii As Long) As Boolean
    IsNavKey = keyAscii = vbKeyTab Or keyAscii = vbKeyLeft Or keyAscii = vbKeyRight
End Function
```

If you wanted to support decimals, you'd pass the current contents of your textbox to `IsValidDecimalInput` (which needs minor adjustments to support international decimal separators).

I actually have that module as a class, but a standard module fits the bill just fine too.

Point being, don't fix your user's input after it's in the textbox - *prevent* the user's invalid input from even being entered in the first place instead.

Comment: Your idea of using preemptive validation of the data is pretty cool.

Comment: I think that there should be an exception added to `IsValidDigitInput` to allow for negative numbers.   The OP also mentions that **The final result has the separator for thousand**.  This approach doesn't allow for copy and paste either.

Comment: @ThomasInzina meh, it can easily be tweaked at will as needed - I'm using this in actual production code where negatives would be illegal (negative cost price? negative product code? negative invoice total?); good point on textbox hotkeys being thwarted though. Gotta think about that one....

Comment: Thank you for your idea,,,,
I forgot something small ... this TextBox is not an input data entrance, in fact, it is an output display for a hidden cell. It related to a cell ("B15") that the cell is set on Separator Thousand Group (On) and No Decimal Place (Off). But the TextBox1 shows the Numbers with Separator T.Group (On) with Decimal Place (On). I need a syntax of VB code for keeping Separator T.Group without Decimal Place.

Comment: Then don't handle a change event.... Assign the textbox with the correct value in the first place!

Comment: Also if the user isn't supposed to be able to change that value, consider locking the textbox, or using a `Label` control. And if the cell is hidden, why does it need a format at all?

Answer (score 3):

Note that both methods (`Format` from the comments on OP, and `Split` from @Gary's Student) effectively prevent the user from inputting the decimal, but they don't truncate or round the (presumably numeric) value, so if the user is trying to enter `123.54` the resulting value will be `12354` when probably you want either of `124` (round) or `123` (trunc).

Relying on _Change event for validation has some limitations :D and probably this value should be validated/manipulated by whatever other procedure is using it as an input.

Example:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call ValidateMe(TextBox1)
    MsgBox (TextBox1.Value)

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    ' do nothing
End Sub

Private Sub ValidateMe(obj As MSForms.TextBox)
    obj.Value = Format(obj, "0")
End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot something small ... this TextBox is not an input data entrance, in fact, it is an output display for a hidden cell. It related to a cell ("B15") that the cell is set on Separator Thousand Group (On) and No Decimal Place (Off). But the TextBox1 shows the Numbers with Separator T.Group (On) with Decimal Place (On). I need a syntax of VB code for keeping Separator T.Group without Decimal Place.

Answer (score 2):

If TextBox1 is a `String` like:

1,234.56

then use something like:

```
TextBox1 = Split(TextBox1,".")(0)
```

**EDIT#1:**

Based on the Comments,this should be used:

```
TextBox1 = Split(TextBox1 & Application.DecimalSeparator, Application.DecimalSeparator)(0)
```

This will:

1. return a null string given a null string
2. return a null string if there is no integer part
3. return the integer part in a Locale-independent fashion

Comment: This will returning the decimal part of the string not the integer part.

Comment: @ThomasInzina  OUCH!  Thanks  I will fix

Comment: FYI: Raises an index out of range if user backspaces to a 0-length string. `Format` seems more reliable.

Comment: @DavidZemens  good point...........should we end up with a null string or a zero??

Comment: Note: both methods effectively prevent the user from inputting the decimal, but they don't truncate or round the (presumably numeric) value, so if the user is trying to enter `123.54` the resulting value will be `12354` when probably you want either of `124` (round) or `123` (trunc). Relying on _Change event for validation has some limitations :D and probably this value should be validated/manipulated by whatever other procedure is using it as an input.

Comment: @Mat'sMug  you are correct! ...............the `Split()` separator must match the locale.

Comment: @Mat'sMug  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: IMO it's an X-Y problem (see answer below)

Comment: Thank you for your idea,,,, I forgot something small ... this TextBox is not an input data entrance, in fact, it is an output display for a hidden cell. It related to a cell ("B15") that the cell is set on Separator Thousand Group (On) and No Decimal Place (Off). But the TextBox1 shows the Numbers with Separator T.Group (On) with Decimal Place (On). I need a syntax of VB code for keeping Separator T.Group without Decimal Place.

Answer (score 0):

**braX** sent this code:

```
TextBox1.Text = Format(TextBox1.Text, "#,###,###,##0")
```

Well done **braX** ,, Thank you, it's worked properly ... :)